# Need row to fill remaining space

Tags: html, css, css-grid

See image to see how it is now. I want the yellow part (`.content`) to push the bottom black part (`.footer`) down and expand to take up all remaining screen space (horizontal and vertical). But as you can see, it does neither. Code at the bottom, after this image:

[image: how it currently looks]

```css
.container {
 height: 100vh;
 width: 100vh;
 display: grid;
 grid-template-columns: 1fr 5fr 1fr;
 grid-template-rows: 2fr 9fr 1fr;
    grid-template-areas: 
    "h h h"
    "c c c"
    "f f f";
 }

.header {
 background-color: #000000;
 grid-area: h;
 justify-items: center; 
 }

.content {
 background-color: #ffff00;
 grid-area: c;
 }

.footer {
 background-color: #000000;
 grid-area: f;
 justify-self: end;
 align-self: end;
 }
```

```html
<div class="container">
 <div class="header">
  <div><a href="index.asp">
  <img src="images/title-img-640.png" class="logo" alt="Play to Evolve" title="Play to Evolve">
  </a></div>
 </div>

 <div class="content">
  What is your reaction to receiving criticism?
 <div>
 
  <div class="footer">
   <div class="textFooterSmall">
   Copyright 2019 ClearSay.net<br>
   </div>
  
  <div></div>

  <div class="textFooterSmall">
  design by <a class="footerlinkSmall" href="http://www.OceanMedia.net" target="_blank">OceanMedia.net</a><br>
  <a class="footerlinkSmall" href="admin_menu.asp">admin</a>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Thank you for any ideas you can share!
Scott

Answer (score 3):

The principal problem is that your `.content` element doesn't have a closing `div`.

```
<div class="content">What is your reaction to receiving criticism?<div>
```

Another problem is that `width: 100vh` doesn't give you the full width you expect.

```
.container {
   height: 100vh;
   width: 100vh;
   display: grid;
       ...
       ...
}
```

You're using *viewport height* units for width. I think you wanted `vw`.

But in the end, you don't need any of it, as block elements take full width by default.

Also, if you want full width, you don't need `end` values.

```
.footer {
    background-color: #000000;
    grid-area: f;
    justify-self: end;
    align-self: end;
 }
```

```css
.container {
  height: 100vh;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 5fr 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: 2fr 9fr 1fr;
  grid-template-areas: "h h h" 
                       "c c c"
                       "f f f";
}

.header {
  grid-area: h;
  background-color: #000000;  
}

.content {
  grid-area: c;
  background-color: #ffff00;  
}

.footer {
  grid-area: f;
  background-color: #000000;  
}

body {
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="header">
    <div>
      <a href="index.asp">
        <img src="images/title-img-640.png" class="logo" alt="Play to Evolve" title="Play to Evolve">
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="content">
    What is your reaction to receiving criticism?
  </div>
  <div class="footer">
    <div class="textFooterSmall">
      Copyright 2019 ClearSay.net<br>
    </div>
    <div></div>
    <div class="textFooterSmall">
      design by <a class="footerlinkSmall" href="http://www.OceanMedia.net" target="_blank">OceanMedia.net</a><br>
      <a class="footerlinkSmall" href="admin_menu.asp">admin</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```